# Compiler error referencing custom C# extension method

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I am trying for the first time to create an extension method and i am having some trouble... maybe you guys can help out :)

```
public static class Extentions
    {
        public static int myMethod(this MyClass c)
        {
              return 1;
        }
    }
```

then when i do "MyClass.myMethod" i get q compiler error saying that the method does not exists...

Why is that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First, you need a "using" directive to include the namespace that includes your class with extension methods.

Second - re "MyClass.myMethod" - extension methods work on *instances*, not as static - so you'd need:

```
MyClass foo = ...
int i = foo.myMethod(); // translates as: int i = Extentions.myMethod(foo);
```

Finally - if you want to use the extension method *inside* `MyClass` (or a subclass), you need an explicit `this` - i.e.

```
int i = this.myMethod(); // translates as: int i = Extentions.myMethod(this);
```

This is one of the few cases where `this` matters.

Comment: Just our of curiosity, why would there ever be a need to call an extension method within a class? If you're coding the class, why is this method an extension in the first place? Shouldn't it just be part of the class itself? (I understand you posted it to show the syntax, but I'm just ciurious).

Comment: The class might implement an interface, with the extension method defined for that interface. Or the code might be in a subclass, with the extension method defined (separately) against the base class - perhaps in a different assembly to the base class.

Comment: Re this last; I use this approach myself to provide C# 3.0/.NET 3.5 extensions to a library that is itself .NET 2.0 - i.e. to allow lambda rather than member-name based usage.

Comment: Marc: I've edited to change '"using" statement' to '"using" directive'. Hope you don't mind :)

Comment: I agree with @BFree -- there's no reason you'd ever *want* to use an extension method from within a class. An extension method extends a class without modifying code. If you're modifying your code, just promote the extension method to a normal member method.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, you should have removed the quotes and put it in a code section. `using` looks much better

Comment: @Jon - as long as you didn't mind me editing your LINQ earlier ;-p

Comment: BFree: "MyClass" belongs to a DLL that I cannot change...

Mark: You are absolutely right about the instance. As soon as I instantiated the object I could access my function. This will lead to another question that I will open soon :)

Comment: @Randolpho; so you'd never want to use GroupBy, Where, or any of the rest of LINQ for some processing within a collection class?

Comment: @Sergio - look forward to it ;-p

Answer (score 6):

Did you include the namespace where your extension is defined?  I've been burned by that before.

And a way to get around having to add the namespace where your extension is to define the extension in that namespace.  This is not a  good practice though

Answer (score 5):

Did you import (`using` clause at the beginning) the namespace in which `Extensions`class is?

```
using Myself.MyProduct.MyNamespace;
```

Comment: They are in the same namespace

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason forcing you to use [Extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)?

You should only be using extension methods if you cannot add the method in the original source and cannot extend the class with a sub-class (if it is declared `sealed`)

The page on Extension methods states:

> In general, we recommend that you
>   implement extension methods sparingly
>   and only when you have to. Whenever
>   possible, client code that must extend
>   an existing type should do so by
>   creating a new type derived from the
>   existing type. For more information,
>   see [Inheritance (C# Programming
>   Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx).

Here is even more info regarding [classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b0thckt.aspx) and [polymorphism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx).

If extending the class is really not a possibility then follow the other answers regarding the `using` directive and instance [methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx) vs [static methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx).

Comment: I need extension methods because I am not allowed to change that particular assembly.

Comment: Is the class also sealed, preventing you from sub-classing it?