# extension methods as static class methods

Tags: c#, extension-methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you add extension methods that you call like static methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877995/can-you-add-extension-methods-that-you-call-like-static-methods)

I would like to add `NewSequentialGuid` function on the `Guid` system type, so I can use like following:

Id = Guid.NewSequentialGuid()

```
namespace MyExtensions
{
    public static class GuidExtensions
    {
        [DllImport("rpcrt4.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int UuidCreateSequential(out Guid guid);

        public static Guid NewSequentialGuid(this Guid guid)
        {
            const int RPC_S_OK = 0;
            Guid g;
            int hr = UuidCreateSequential(out g);
            if (hr != RPC_S_OK)
                throw new ApplicationException
                  ("UuidCreateSequential failed: " + hr);
            return g;
        }
    }
}
```

But I cannot get this to work, it only works with instance variables, any idea how to add this to extended class as a static method?

Comment: You realize that this does *not* return guids that are in any way sequential, right?

Comment: My understanding is that, this creates sequential guids until the next restart of the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

They were created to look like instance methods and can't be make to work as class (static) methods.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx):

> Extension methods are a special kind of static method, but they are called as if they were instance methods on the extended type.

And:

> Extension methods are defined as static methods but are called by using instance method syntax.

Answer (score 0):

[Can you add extension methods that you call like static methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877995/can-you-add-extension-methods-that-you-call-like-static-methods)

Comment: Normally best to add this as a comment to the question, rather than an answer. It's a duplicate question.